# how to replace all occurences of a word in a string with another word in java?

Tags: java, string, replace

I want to replace all occurrences of a word in a long string with another word, for example if I am wanting to change all occurrences of the word "very" with "extremely" in the following string.

```
string story = "He became a well decorated soldier in the line of fire when he and his men walked into the battle. He acted very bravely and he was very courageous."
```

I guess I would use the `replaceAll()` method but would I simply insert the words such as

```
story.replaceAll("very ", "extremely ");
```

Comment: If this is Java then `string` should be capitalized.

Answer (score 17):

You need to make two changes:

- Strings are immutable in Java - the `replaceAll` method doesn't modify the string - it creates a new one. You need to assign the result of the call back to your variable.
- Use word boundaries (`'\b'`) otherwise `every` will become `eextremely`.

So your code would look like this:

```
story = story.replaceAll("\\bvery\\b", "extremely");
```

You may also want to consider what you want to happen to "Very" or "VERY". For example, you might want this to become "Extremely" and "EXTREMELY" respectively.

Answer (score 2):

```
story = story.replaceAll("very ", "extremely ");
```

Answer (score -1):

message=message.replaceAll("\\b"+word+"\\b",newword);